# how it is possible add null to string, but result would not be null?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I simulated my code to simple one like this:

```
select 'a'+
(
    select 'b'+
    (
        select 'c'
        from tbl_one t3
        inner join tbl_alpha a t3.id=a.id
        where t1.id=t3.id
        for xml path('')
    )
    from tbl_one t2
    where t1.id=t2.id
    for xml path('')
)
from tbl_one t1
```

if my `select 'c'` part be null, my result should be null, but I don't know what happened, I did not get null result, and only `select 'a'` part shown.
I expected my result be `NULL` or `abc` but my query just give me `'a'`
so I do not have any explanation to debug my query.

Comment: I tried to [reproduce](http://rextester.com/FGHSQ7055) it but couldn't. Can you create a [mcve]?

Comment: @ZoharPeled acctually I did not get this error on other examples, but suppose tbl_one is sys.schemas and tbl_alpha is sys.tables
if you jined them correctly you will get `abc` if not `NULL` I acctually do not know why my query give me just `a` I asked to see if someone else had this issue, tell me what to do. thanks :)

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the relevant tables DDL + some DML for sample data that reproduce the problem?

Comment: @ZoharPeled yes man sure :))
but I did not get what to do? could you please explain more that what should I do?

Comment: DDL - data definition language - meaning the create table statements for all relevant tables. DML - data manipulation language - meaning the insert statements for the sample data. If you can post them (and make sure that the data you posted actually reproduce the problem) then we might have something to work with.

Comment: @ZoharPeled I get my answer man, for xml path('') will change null to empty string.I did not mentioned for xml path('') one of my colleges checked my code and tell me :)

Comment: Glad you solved the problem :-)

Comment: @ZoharPeled thanks man! :)))